# Quick questions about Linux kernel modules

Tags: linux, kernel, c

I'm very familiar with Linux (I've been using it for 2 years, no Windows for 1 1/2 years), and I'm finally digging deeper into kernel programming and I'm working a project. So my questions are:

1. Will a kernel module run faster than a traditional c program.
2. How can I communicate with a module (is that even possible), for example call a function in it.

Comment: SO is a better resource. They can give you a more complete answer than we could. Kernel mode _can_ be faster, it usually depends on what the module is actually doing. Kernel mode doesn't usually make the code run faster, it just gives you unlimited access which lets you be more direct about what you want to accomplish. As for communicating, modules take parameters at startup, and can create files in `/proc` (for purely kernel related stuff) or `/sys` for kernel modules relating to hardware. You can create a file somewhere in either one that when written to executes some function's code.

Comment: 1. Why do you have this question of if kernel module with run faster? Its just a code running on CPU. If you are talking about priority time slice, then its difference discussion. 2. You export (non-static)the function of module and then call it from other module.

Comment: "Will a kernel module run faster than a traditional c program" - a kernel model *is* a C program.

Answer (score 6):

> 1.Will a kernel module run faster than a traditional c program.

It Depends™
Running as a kernel module means you get to play by different rules, you potentially get to avoid some context switches depending on what you are doing. You get access to some powerful tools that can be leveraged to optimize your code, but don't expect your code to run magically faster just by throwing everything in kernelspace.

> 2.How can I communicate with a module (is that even possible), for example call a function in it.

There are various ways:

- You can use the various file system interfaces: [procfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs), [sysfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs), [debugfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugfs), [sysctl](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sysctl), ...
- You could register [a char device](https://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch03.pdf)
- You can make use of [the Netlink interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink)
- You could create new syscalls, although that's heavily discouraged
- And you can always come up with your own scheme, or use some less common APIs

Comment: To second part: are there any syscall that enter to your module code without read/write to `sysfs`/`procfs`? What about `ioctrl` call that usually hard to map to fs hierarchy?

Comment: @gavenkoa Yes, you can create new syscalls that don't go through `sysfs`/`procfs`, but that's seriously frowned upon.  Not sure what your question about `ioctl` is, though. You can [look here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) for more infos on the Linux syscall interface.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Will a kernel module run faster than a traditional c program.

The kernel is already a C program, which is most likely be compiled with same compiler you use. So generic algorithms or some processor intensive computations will be executed with almost same speed.

But most *userspace* programs (like `bash`) have to ask *kernel* to perform some operations on system resources, i.e. print prompt onto monitor. It will require entering the kernel with system call, sending data over `tty` interfaces and passing to a video-driver, it may introduce some latency. If you'd implemented bash in-kernel, you may directly call video-driver, which is definitely faster.

That approach however, have drawbacks. First of all, `bash` should be able to print prompt on ssh-session or serial console, and that will complicate logic. Also, if your `bash` will hang, you cannot just kill, you have to reboot system.

> 2. How can I communicate with a module (is that even possible), for example call a function in it.

In addition to excellent list provided by @tux3, I would suggest to start with *char devices*.